# how can i get android list view selector items to remember their state off screen?

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom list view that has two arrows (up/down for voting) on the left side of each row. Using selectors I have been able to change the image(colour) of the arrows and update the votes accordingly. My problem is that if I click vote up for example, as soon as i scroll down far enough so that the list item i voted on goes off the screen it resets to the original un-checked state/image.

here's my get view method

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //creating the ViewHolder we defined earlier.
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(); 

        //creating LayoutInflator for inflating the row layout.
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflating the row layout we defined earlier.
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.partylist, null);

        //setting the views into the ViewHolder.
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.voteUp = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vote_up_image);
        holder.voteUp.setTag(position);
        holder.voteDown = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vote_down_image);
        holder.voteDown.setTag(position);
        holder.votes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.votes);

        //define an onClickListener for the ImageView.
        holder.voteUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            { 
                if (v.isSelected()){
                    v.setSelected(false);
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes)));
                } else {
                    if (holder.voteDown.isSelected()){
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    holder.voteDown.setSelected(false);
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes+1)));
                    }else{
                        v.setSelected(true);
                    }
                }

                //Toast.makeText(PartyActivity.this, "Image from row " + position + " was pressed " + list.get(position).title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        holder.voteDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View w) 
            { 
                if (w.isSelected()){
                    w.setSelected(false);
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes)));
                } else {
                    if (holder.voteUp.isSelected()){
                    w.setSelected(true);
                    holder.voteUp.setSelected(false);
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes-1)));
                    }else{
                        w.setSelected(true);
                    }
                }

                //Toast.makeText(PartyActivity.this, "Image from row " + position + " was pressed " + list.get(position).title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        //setting data into the the ViewHolder.
        holder.title.setText(list.get(position).title);
        holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).votes));
        //return the row view.
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into `SharedPreferences`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: I'm a bit new to android and java and after a quick google im not understanding what shared preferences does and how to implement it..

Comment: The two second version is that `SharedPreferences` is a way to store data while your app is not running. Its sort of like written to a file. As for how to use it, google some examples.

Comment: I don't think shared preferences will help in this case as the problem is with properly selecting items in the list. From my own research the way that works is to use the Checkable interface - see my solution below. Lists are not really meant to be selectable by design in touch mode in Android, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself. It was caused by a terrible understanding of tutorials.

I pass an object to my custom adapter and all I had to do was create a few boolean variables inside the object to store whether the checkbox/selectors were selected on each row and then set those variables appropriately when the images were clicked.

heres my new getview() for anyone who needs help

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //creating the ViewHolder we defined earlier.
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(); 

        //creating LayoutInflator for inflating the row layout.
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflating the row layout we defined earlier.
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.partylist, null);

        //setting the views into the ViewHolder.
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.voteUp = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vote_up_image);
        holder.voteUp.setTag(position);
        holder.voteDown = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vote_down_image);
        holder.voteDown.setTag(position);
        holder.votes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.votes);




        //define an onClickListener for the ImageView.

        holder.voteUp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if (holder.voteUp.isSelected()){
                    holder.voteUp.setSelected(false);
                    list.get(position).Up=false;
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes)));
                } else {
                    if (holder.voteDown.isSelected()){
                    holder.voteUp.setSelected(true);
                    holder.voteDown.setSelected(false);
                    list.get(position).Up=true;
                    list.get(position).Down=false;
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes+1)));
                    }else{
                        holder.voteUp.setSelected(true);
                        list.get(position).Up=true;
                        holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes+1)));
                    }

            }}
        });

        holder.voteDown.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {// Toast.makeText(PartyActivity.this, "Image from row " + position + " was pressed " + list.get(position).title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (holder.voteDown.isSelected()){
                    holder.voteDown.setSelected(false);
                    list.get(position).Down=false;
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes)));
                } else {
                    if (holder.voteUp.isSelected()){
                    holder.voteDown.setSelected(true);
                    holder.voteUp.setSelected(false);
                    list.get(position).Down=true;
                    list.get(position).Up=false;
                    holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes-1)));
                    }else{
                        holder.voteDown.setSelected(true);
                        list.get(position).Down=true;
                        holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf((list.get(position).votes-1)));
                    }

            }}
        }); 


        //setting data into the the ViewHolder.
        holder.title.setText(list.get(position).title);
        holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).votes));
        holder.voteUp.setChecked(list.get(position).Up);
        holder.voteDown.setChecked(list.get(position).Down);
        //return the row view.
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to create a custom RelativeLayout that implements Checkable. I'm using a background colour to mark the selected item but you could use an image too:

```
package com.xxx;

public class DictionaryRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

public DictionaryRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DictionaryRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private boolean mChecked = false;

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    mChecked = checked;
    this.setBackgroundColor(mChecked ? 
            getResources().getColor(R.color.list_selected) : 
                getResources().getColor(R.color.list_default));
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}
}
```

The I use that RelativeLayout when I define the layout for my list item:

```
<com.xxx.DictionaryRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/list_margin" >

... the rest of the layout

</com.xxx.DictionaryRelativeLayout>
```

I use my list in a fragment and you have to define that you're list is using single selection. I do it in onActivityCreated:

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
 }
```

Comment: would this relative layout class be a sub-class of my main activity? would i have to re-do my custom arrayadapter that already extends arrayadapter<object> ?

Comment: @Chris That's just a class that extends RelativeLayout. You can always extend most of the classes and use them in place of the original classes.
It's used in the layout of the items on the list. That layout is used in your adapter to inflate the view, I assume. You wouldn't have to change your adapter, I think but if you have any problems, let me know.

Comment: do I need the relative layout? Could I just implement Checkable on my customarrayadapter (the class that holds the getView I posted earlier)? Im using a holder so would I need to add mChecked to the holder? I need mChecked to represent every row

Comment: No, you can use any other layout.
You don't need to change the adapter at all, if I remember correctly (I don't have the code in front of me now). You need to change the item's layout - the one that gets inflated in the adapter.

Comment: trying to implement this.. will this one class work for two selectors in each row?  How do I call the functions from within my customadapter class' getView-OnClicks?(if you look at my description I currently call the selectors directly)I named the class partylist because my custom row layout is called partylist. So I tried partylist.isChecked() but its telling me the function needs to be static or static final.. also im getting an error inflating class.. I replaced XXX with my package.activity path

I appreciate your help I'm really struggling with this

Comment: From memory, you don't need to handle onclick events any more.

I'll come back to you later, I'm at work now and can't check my code now.

Comment: Do you think itd be easier for me to use a check box instead of the selectors?

Comment: It may be easier but I think it doesn't look that pretty. Depends on what you need.

Comment: @Chris I checked that you don't need to implement onclick at all. What is important though is to call setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) on the ListView.

Comment: thanks for the help I ended up figuring it out although i didnt use this class, I still appreciate it.