# Show Hide TextView in listview adapter on ItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

TextView referenced by holder.four is visible when my listview is populated. When i select a row element, i want holder.four to become visible for the selected row but when i select another row, i want the previous holder.four visible to become invisible and the new selected position row holder.four to become visible. How can i achieve this. Here is my getview method that populate the listview.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_operation, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_on);
            holder.two = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_messag);
            holder.three = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_th);
            holder.four = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_details);

            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_operation, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_on);
        holder.two = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_messag);
        holder.three = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_th);
        holder.four = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_details);

        vi.setTag(holder);

        holder.one.setText(data.get(position).getmontant()+" EUR");
        holder.two.setText((data.get(position).getlibelle()));
        holder.three.setText(data.get(position).getdateValeur());

        holder.four.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.four.setText(data.get(position).getdateOper());

        //clickEvent();

        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: On List Selection or on List Item Click???

Comment: yes but when i use onitemclicklistener the row is successfully visible but when i select another row the previous row remains visible. I delete my code because it was not the right way to do it.

Comment: Just use the reference of previous list row's 4th `TextView` and on every list item click Check for it Visibility if its `Visible` then make it `Gone`.

Comment: store the position index of currently selected item in a variable and make its visibility gone when you select another one and update the variable to the newly selected one's position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go :

```
Holder selectedHolder;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_operation, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_on);
        holder.two = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_messag);
        holder.three = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_th);
        holder.four = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_details);

        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    //vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_operation, null);
    //holder = new ViewHolder();
    //holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_on);
    //holder.two = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_messag);
    //holder.three = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_th);
    //holder.four = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_details);


    holder.one.setText(data.get(position).getmontant()+" EUR");
    holder.two.setText((data.get(position).getlibelle()));
    holder.three.setText(data.get(position).getdateValeur());

    holder.four.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.four.setText(data.get(position).getdateOper());


    //clickEvent();
    vi.setTag(holder);

    vi.setOnClickListener(this);
    return vi;
}
@Overrite

public void onClick(View v){
    v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewHolder holder = ((ViewHolder)v.getTag());
            holder.four.setVisibility(View.VISIABLE);
            if(selectedHolder != null)
                selectedHolder.four.setVisibility(View.INVISABLE);
            selectedHolder = holder;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer for this question: [how can i get android list view selector items to remember their state off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728240/how-can-i-get-android-list-view-selector-items-to-remember-their-state-off-scree/18728917#18728917)

I think you may use a similar idea: extend the layout of the item. Once you've done that, you can also create custom events and capture them where you need them.