# NPE on ListView when trying to set a background color to one particular row.

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView and a handler and one media player. The list view is backed by a String array which contains verses of the lyrics. Now as the song progresses, I want the particular row at that time with lyrics to be the first view in the list and it be highlighted. I have the following code in a handler:

```
public void run(){
                        int X = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        S1.setText(""+X);
                        setProgressText();
                        seek_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                            if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 0 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 20){
                            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(3);
                            View element = listView.getChildAt(3);
                            element.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                        }else if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 > 20 && mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000 < 54){
                            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(4);
                            View element = listView.getChildAt(4);
                            element.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


                System.out.println("2 if");
```

The first if condition is executing perfectly well, however at the second if condition I get a NPE.

Here is my Log Cat:

```
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.mobiligent.stotram.MainActivity$1$2.run(MainActivity.java:183)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-23 10:13:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: element.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); in the second if else. I put a second check and came to know that listView.getChildAt(4); is returning null. But I am unable to understand how do I scroll a specific row in a listview to the top and change its background color.

Comment: Check my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728240/how-can-i-get-android-list-view-selector-items-to-remember-their-state-off-scree/18728917#18728917. I highlight an item in a different way, basically using a checkable layout as a background. Works very well but is a bit complicated.

Comment: Onto it! Let me have a look!

Answer (score 0):

getChildAt(4) returns null because getChildCount() returns <= 4, check it out

Comment: How to overcome this?

Comment: see ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()